# System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 3

Tags: apex, date

```
 String  dateSplit = '2015/05/05'
 List<String> arr = new List<String>();
 arr = dateSplit.split('/');

 String tempDate = '';
 for(Integer i=arr.Size();i>=0;i--){
    if(tempDate == ''){
        tempDate = arr[i];
    }
    else{
        tempDate = tempDate + '/' + arr[i];
    }
 }
 Date depDate = Date.parse(tempDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

akash,
is this code just for your learning ? why do you use hard coded dates and convert the format and parse it ?

[Date.parse](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_parse) usually parses the string into date using **user's locale date format**.

so no point in changing the format to pass it to parse method.

now to the error you are getting,

- its becos you are starting the loop from `arr.size()` which is always 1
  plus index of the last element stored in the array (since arrays starts
  storing element from 0 index)
- so start your looping from `arr.size()-1` and you should be good